# vim syntax - How to highlight a match inside a region

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a vim syntax highlighting script to determine if a global param is in uppercase only. If its not - I want to highlight it.
The problem is that the global params is in a specific part in the page.

The code looks something like this:

```
***VARS***
${VAR1}
${var2}

***OTHERS***
${var3}
```

So I want that all the variables under ***VARS*** which contains lowercase to be highlighted - in my example, only ${var2} should be highlighted.

I tried to do this:

```
syn match global_var_match "\${.*[a-z][^}]+}" contained
syn region global_variables start="\(\*\*\*VARS\*\*\*\)\@<=" end="\(\*\*\* OTHERS\*\*\*\)\@=" contains=global_var_match 
hi link global_variables ErrorMsg
```

But then also ${VAR1} and ${var2} is highlighted.

Comment: Note that `\${.*[a-z][^}]+}` should probably be `\${[^}]*[a-z][^}]*}`.   The `.*` will match the closing `}`; and what if the lower-case character is just before the closing `}`?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the simple typo in:

```
hi link global_variables ErrorMsg
```

This should be

```
hi link global_var_match ErrorMsg
```

I.e. the bad match, not the containing region. However, with this change, variables containing lower case are still matched under `***OTHERS***`.

That issue is caused by a spurious space you have in your match for `***OTHERS***`.

I also chhanged your `global_var_match` regex. I have it as:

```
syn match global_var_match "\${[^}]*[a-z][^}]*}" contained
```

This behaves very well for me in test cases like

```
${VAR} blah ${VAr} ${vAR}
```

and others: only the vars containing lower case are flagged. Still investigating why the region is incorrect.

Here is what I have:

```
syn match global_var_match "\${[^}]*[a-z][^}]*}" contained
syn region global_variables start="\(\*\*\*VARS\*\*\*\)\@<=" end="\(\*\*\*OTHERS
\*\*\*\)\@=" contains=global_var_match
hi link global_var_match ErrorMsg
```